# Laravel 4 package not loading class path properly

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I am having trouble with loading classes in one of my Laravel 4 packages. I get the common "Class Not Found" error, which happens when `composer.json` does not have the proper namespace-path mapping. I have tried adding everything to the `composer.json` file, but nothing seems to work, not `psr-0`, nor `classmap`, nor `files`. However, if I try to use the full path of the class when declaring a new object:

`$foo=new Myvendor\Mypackage\Domain\Models\Mymodel;`

it works quite well. However, I don't want to have to declare the entire path every time I need the object. The fact that the class with the full filepath works shows me that I'm getting very close to the solution.

Edited: Some code

My class, which is located on:`src\Myvendor\Mypackage\Domain\Models\Complainant.php` relative to the package root

```
<?php namespace Myvendor\Mypackage\Domain\Models;

class Complainant {
public $fname;
public $lname;
}
```

A part of my `composer.json` file:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "Myvendor\\Mypackage": "src/"
    }
},
```

This code does not work:

```
$var=new Complainant;
```

While the following does:

```
$c=new Myvendor\Mypackage\Domain\Models\Complainant;
```

Comment: have you done composer dump after you update composer.json?

Comment: Yes, I used `composer dump-autoload` each time I changed composed.json

Comment: You are probably using the namespaces wrong. Show actual code and actual errors. This question isn't very helpful.

Comment: okay that all looks fine, but you say the only issue is when not using the full namespaced class name? sure you didn't just make an error when doing the "use"?

Comment: @Robbo I added some code which I believe is relevant to my problem

Comment: yeah I saw, added a new comment above

Comment: Can you give me an example of the proper use?

Comment: <?php Whatever\New\Namespace; use MyVendor\MyPackage\Domain\Models\Complainant; // use class without absolute namespace here

Comment: Learn how to use namespaces. This problem is not relevant to composer or laravel.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing `php artisan dump-autoload`, you can see all classes are mapped in file `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` with their proper namespace. Locate your class over there and use the proper namespace.